PHP memory_limit is not updating for any user, only for root under Debian 12
I have a Debian 12 system, where I use PHP in cli mode. In /etc/php/8.2/cli/php.ini I set the memory limit:
memory_limit = 1024M

If I query it with root, it shows me the right value. But if I use sudo to query with any other user, it shows the wrong value:
root@XXX:~# php -i |grep memory_limit
memory_limit => 1024M => 1024M
root@XXX:~# sudo -u www-data php -i |grep memory_limit
memory_limit => 128M => 128M

What could be the issue? Based on the full phpinfo, the usual php.ini files are used, there is no other reference for this:
root@XXX:~# grep -r -i "memory_limit" /etc/php/8.2/cli/
/etc/php/8.2/cli/php.ini:memory_limit = 1024M

and no other matches.
UPDATE:
As requested, the output of the command for sudo -u www-data php -i | grep 'Configuration File' is this:
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc/php/8.2/cli
Loaded Configuration File => (none)

And the output of the command for php -i | grep 'Configuration File' is this
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc/php/8.2/cli
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php/8.2/cli/php.ini

I see the difference, the root one has loaded configuration but the www-data one is not. I guess that could be the issue. What I don't understand, why is that loaded for root and not for any other user?

What is the output of sudo -u www-data php -i | grep 'Configuration File' and does it match php -i | grep 'Configuration File' run as root?  Might also be helpful to post the output of php --version run from both user accounts.

I posted out the result of the 2 command, that could be the issue. I didn't post the version, they are exactly the same, but it can be seen from the ini file path.

Does the www-data have permissions to read /etc/php/8.2/cli/php.ini?  Check the permissions of the file and each directory above it.

You are right, the php.ini file had a 640 permission. After changed it to 644 it works as expected. If you write it as answer, I will accept it. Thank you to point me out to the right way!

When PHP runs as a user, that user needs to have permissions to read the php.ini file or PHP will run with the defaults it was built with.
You can find the configuration path with php -i | grep 'Configuration File'.  If PHP reports Loaded Configuration File => (none) then a php.ini could not be read or does not exist within the Configuration File (php.ini) Path.
If there is a php.ini file within that path, make sure it is readable by the users that need access to it.
